# R - reduce with merge and more than 2 suffixes (or: how to merge multiple dataframes and keep track of columns)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge 4 dataframes based on 2 columns, but keep track of which dataframe a column originated from. I'm running into an issue at tracking the columns.

(see end of post of dput(dfs))

```
#df example (df1)
Name    Color    Freq
banana  yellow   3
apple   red      1
apple   green    4
plum    purple   8


#create list of dataframes
list.df <- list(df1, df2, df3, df4)

#merge dfs on column "Name" and "Color"
combo.df <- Reduce(function(x,y) merge(x,y, by = c("Name", "Color"), all = TRUE, accumulate=FALSE, suffixes = c(".df1", ".df2", ".df3", ".df4")), list.df)
```

This gives the following warning:

> Warning message:
>   In merge.data.frame(x, y, by = c("Name", "Color"), all = TRUE,  :
>     column names ‘Freq.df1’, ‘Freq.df2’ are duplicated in the result

and outputs this dataframe:

```
#combo df example
Name    Color    Freq.df1   Freq.df2  Freq.df1  Freq.df2
banana  yellow   3          3         7         NA
apple   red      1          2         9         1
apple   green    4          NA        8         2
plum    purple   8          1         NA        6
```

`df1` and `df2` are only repeated in name. The values populating the third and fourth column of `combo` are actually from `df3` and `df4` respectively.

What I would really like is:

```
Name    Color    Freq.df1   Freq.df2  Freq.df3  Freq.df4
banana  yellow   3          3         7         NA
apple   red      1          2         9         1
apple   green    4          NA        8         2
plum    purple   8          1         NA        6
```

How can I achieve this? I know the `merge(..., suffixes)` function can only handle a character vector of 2, but I don't know what the work around should be.  Thanks!

```
df1 <- 
structure(list(Name = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("apple", 
"banana", "plum"), class = "factor"), Color = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("green", "purple", "red", "yellow"), class = "factor"), 
    Freq = c(3, 1, 4, 8)), .Names = c("Name", "Color", "Freq"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = "data.frame")

df2 <-
structure(list(Name = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("apple", 
"banana", "plum"), class = "factor"), Color = structure(c(3L, 
2L, 1L), .Label = c("purple", "red", "yellow"), class = "factor"), 
    Freq = c(3, 2, 1)), .Names = c("Name", "Color", "Freq"), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = "data.frame")

df3 <-
structure(list(Name = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("apple", 
"banana"), class = "factor"), Color = structure(c(3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("green", 
"red", "yellow"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(7, 9, 8)), .Names = c("Name", 
"Color", "Freq"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")

df4 <-
structure(list(Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("apple", 
"plum"), class = "factor"), Color = structure(c(3L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("green", 
"purple", "red"), class = "factor"), Freq = c(1, 2, 6)), .Names = c("Name", 
"Color", "Freq"), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: could you please share all 4 `data.frames` using `dput` ?

Comment: @TUSHAr - edited in post

Comment: This is very tricky. Not sure if it can be elegantly tracked while the merge is taking place. All we can do is pass names of the `data.frame` as external values in the same order as we expect the merge to take place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be easier with a `for` loop as the `Reduce` or `reduce` (`purrr`) at a time takes only two datasets, so we can't have more than two `suffixes` in the `merge`.

Here, we created a vector of suffixes ('sfx').  Initialize an output dataset with the first `list` element.  Then loop through the sequence of 'list.df' and do a sequential `merge` with the 'res' and the next element of `list.df` while updating the 'res' in each step

```
sfx <- c(".df1", ".df2", ".df3", ".df4")
res <- list.df[[1]]
for(i in head(seq_along(list.df), -1)) {

 res <- merge(res, list.df[[i+1]], all = TRUE, 
                 suffixes = sfx[i:(i+1)], by = c("Name", "Color"))
  }

res
#    Name  Color Freq.df1 Freq.df2 Freq.df3 Freq.df4
#1  apple  green        4       NA        8        2
#2  apple    red        1        2        9        1
#3 banana yellow        3        3        7       NA
#4   plum purple        8        1       NA        6
```

Comment: For some reason this duplicates the columns of first df. One set of columns will be called "column name.df1", the second set of columns appear at the end of the result as "column name"

Answer (score 2):

I finally could make this one work using `Reduce` function itself. To do so I modified the input in a particular format.

As we could not pass the names of the `data.frame` as parameter inside the `Reduce` function, I created a list with an attribute `n` containing the name of the data.frame.

```
lst=list(list(n="df1",df=df1),list(n="df2",df=df2),list(n="df3",df=df3), list(n="df4",df=df4))
```

Around that I have built the logic to track the name of the `data.frames` being processed.

```
Reduce(function(x,y){
    if(ncol(x$df)==3){
      #df column names after 1st merge.
      namecol=c('Name','Color',paste0("Freq.",x$n),paste0("Freq.",y$n))
    }else{
        #df column names for remaining merges.
        namecol=c(colnames(x$df),paste0("Freq.",y$n))
    }
    df=merge.data.frame(x = x$df,y = y$df,by = c("Name","Color"),all = TRUE)
    colnames(df)=namecol
    list(n="df",df=df)},lst)


#$n
#[1] "df"

#$df
#    Name  Color Freq.df1 Freq.df2 Freq.df3 Freq.df4
#1  apple  green        4       NA        8        2
#2  apple    red        1        2        9        1
#3 banana yellow        3        3        7       NA
#4   plum purple        8        1       NA        6
```

Answer (score 0):

The function `eat` of my package safejoin has such feature, if you give
it a named list of data.frames as a second input it will join them
recursively to the first input prefixing the new columns with this name.
we'll have to rename separately.

```
# devtools::install_github("moodymudskipper/safejoin")
library(safejoin)
library(dplyr)
eat(rename(df1,df1_Freq = Freq), lst(df2,df3,df4),
    .by = c("Name","Color"), .mode= "full",.check="")
#     Name  Color df1_Freq df2_Freq df3_Freq df4_Freq
# 1 banana yellow        3        3        7       NA
# 2  apple    red        1        2        9        1
# 3  apple  green        4       NA        8        2
# 4   plum purple        8        1       NA        6
```

`.mode = "full"` is to make a full outer join, though here the default (left join), gives the same result.

`.check = ""` is to remove checks, which would warn that the factors have different levels among join columns.