# Merging odd number of data frames with suffixes

Tags: r, join, merge, dplyr, purrr

I am trying to merge a list of data frames, and I came across many different answers in this community like this [R - reduce with merge and more than 2 suffixes (or: how to merge multiple dataframes and keep track of columns)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799959/r-reduce-with-merge-and-more-than-2-suffixes-or-how-to-merge-multiple-datafr) . But after working out on these answers it works on even number of data frames but not odd number of dataframes.

```
myDF <- cbind(typecar = rownames(mtcars), mtcars)
rownames(myDF) <- NULL
df1 <- myDF
df2 <-  myDF
df3<- myDF
df4 <- myDF

for(i in head(seq_along(list.df), -1)) {

  res <- merge(res, list.df[[i+1]], all = TRUE, 
               suffixes = sfx[i:(i+1)], by = "typecar")
}
```

Here the above code works as expected for even number of df, like following

```
list.df <- list(df1, df2, df3,df4)
sfx <- c(".df1", ".df2", ".df3", ".df4")
```

But when trying on odd number the last .df3 is not added as suffix

```
list.df <- list(df1, df2, df3)
sfx <- c(".df1", ".df2", ".df3")
```

here the colnames looks like this.

```
 [1] "typecar"  "mpg.df1"  "cyl.df1"  "disp.df1" "hp.df1"   "drat.df1" "wt.df1"   "qsec.df1" "vs.df1"   "am.df1"   "gear.df1" "carb.df1" "mpg.df2" 
[14] "cyl.df2"  "disp.df2" "hp.df2"   "drat.df2" "wt.df2"   "qsec.df2" "vs.df2"   "am.df2"   "gear.df2" "carb.df2" "mpg"      "cyl"      "disp"    
[27] "hp"       "drat"     "wt"       "qsec"     "vs"       "am"       "gear"     "carb"
```

what I want is

```
 [1] "typecar"  "mpg.df1"  "cyl.df1"  "disp.df1" "hp.df1"   "drat.df1" "wt.df1"   "qsec.df1" "vs.df1"   "am.df1"   "gear.df1" "carb.df1" "mpg.df2" 
[14] "cyl.df2"  "disp.df2" "hp.df2"   "drat.df2" "wt.df2"   "qsec.df2" "vs.df2"   "am.df2"   "gear.df2" "carb.df2" "mpg.df3"      "cyl.df3"      "disp.df3"    
[27] "hp.df3"       "drat.df3"     "wt.df3"       "qsec.df3"     "vs.df3"       "am.df3"       "gear.df3"     "carb.df3"
```

Tried with dplyr join but its the same case. Came across this https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/1296 . Is there any approach to this that work on odd number of data frames ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easier option is to name the `list` element column names with the corresponding `list` names or object names as suffix except the column name used as `by` variable in the `merge`.

```
list.df <- Map(function(x, nm) {i1 <- names(x) != 'typecar'
            names(x)[i1] <- paste0(names(x)[i1], ".", nm)
            x
    }, list.df, names(list.df))
```

Then, we make use of `Reduce/merge`

```
out <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by = 'typecar', all = TRUE), list.df)
names(out)
#[1] "typecar"  "mpg.df1"  "cyl.df1"  "disp.df1" "hp.df1"   "drat.df1" "wt.df1"   "qsec.df1" "vs.df1"   "am.df1"   "gear.df1" "carb.df1"
#[13] "mpg.df2"  "cyl.df2"  "disp.df2" "hp.df2"   "drat.df2" "wt.df2"   "qsec.df2" "vs.df2"   "am.df2"   "gear.df2" "carb.df2" "mpg.df3" 
#[25] "cyl.df3"  "disp.df3" "hp.df3"   "drat.df3" "wt.df3"   "qsec.df3" "vs.df3"   "am.df3"   "gear.df3" "carb.df3"
```

#### data

```
list.df <- mget(paste0('df', 1:3))
```

Comment: tried this ..Reduce(function(dtf1, dtf2) merge(dtf1, dtf2, by = c("typecar"), all = TRUE),list.df)

Comment: @johnsmith0 Do you want to remove the suffix

Comment: I want to add suffix. like this sfx <- c(".df1", ".df2", ".df3") for 3 data frames

Comment: its similar to how you answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48799959/r-reduce-with-merge-and-more-than-2-suffixes-or-how-to-merge-multiple-datafr But it works only when data frames are even

Comment: This is brilliant solution, dint thought about changing the colnames at first. I am trying to work out this in my dataset. getting error Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length. So I am trying to see what went wrong.

Comment: @johnsmith0 I used `Map` instead of `mapply`

Comment: I never used map. could you please tell me what is happening in Map. Still trying to figure out whats happening with my dataset

Comment: @johnsmith0 What is the ouptut after ` Map(function(x, nm) {i1 <- names(x) != 'typecar'
            names(x)[i1] <- paste0(names(x)[i1], ".", nm)
            x
    }, list.df, names(list.df))`

Comment: with my dataset im getting following error Error in mapply(FUN = f, ..., SIMPLIFY = FALSE) : 
  zero-length inputs cannot be mixed with those of non-zero length

Comment: with example dataset > list.df
$df1
 [1] "mpg.df1"  "cyl.df1"  "disp.df1" "hp.df1"   "drat.df1" "wt.df1"   "qsec.df1" "vs.df1"   "am.df1"   "gear.df1" "carb.df1"

$df2
 [1] "mpg.df2"  "cyl.df2"  "disp.df2" "hp.df2"   "drat.df2" "wt.df2"   "qsec.df2" "vs.df2"   "am.df2"   "gear.df2" "carb.df2"

$df3
 [1] "mpg.df3"  "cyl.df3"  "disp.df3" "hp.df3"   "drat.df3" "wt.df3"   "qsec.df3" "vs.df3"   "am.df3"   "gear.df3" "carb.df3"

Comment: @johnsmith0 can you please show a  small reproducible example that shows the error

Comment: im checking that out ... will put here shortly.

Comment: @johnsmith0 IN this dataset, which one is the `by` variable.  In the example, you showed, it was 'typecar'.  So, if that is not the case.  you need to change `names(x) != 'typecar'

Comment: Perfect. I was doing list.df <- list( ). So it dint got the names that why it was throwing that error. when I did mget like you said it worked. Thanks a lot, exactly what I was looking for

Comment: @johnsmith0 I used `mget` so that it gets automaticlaly named and then can I used the `names(list.df)` in `Map` or else I have to `list(df1 = df1, df2 = df2, df3 = df3)`. WIth `dplyr::lst(df1, df2, df3)` gets it named

Comment: Brilliant ! Thanks @akrun

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
do.call(rbind,list.df)
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel. But I am mentioning about joins, not row binds. I updated the question.